# C++ Linking 3rd party dll in diffrent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have an own dll which uses a 3rd party dll, included via its lib file.
Compiling works fine and run-time works also, if the 3rd party dll is in the working directory.

But now I want to move the 3rd party dll into a different folder and then my dll fails to load because the 3rd party dll fails to load, because it cannot be found.

Where (VS2010) or how can I define the folder of the 3rd party dll which should be used during run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we should distinguish two scenarios:

1) [Load-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684184(v=vs.85).aspx) - when you link your code against a stub library to resolve the references to the functions of the DLL at link time and then the system tries to load the DLL when the program starts (and terminates the program if the DLL is not found) and you have basically no control of that. Judging from what you have said you are using this option.

2) [Run-Time Dynamic Linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685090(v=vs.85).aspx) - when you load the DLL yourself by `LoadLibrary`/`LoadLibraryEx` and resolve the needed symbols at runtime. Here you have much greater control of what is going on (among other thins you have the ability to specify what and from where to load). Maybe it makes sense to switch to this mechanism if you need a custom layout?

So what needs to happen for both scenarios to work:

1) The system basically searches for the DLL you are trying to load and any DLLs it may depend on in a set of predefined search paths. So, as mentioned by m.s. you can append the path that contains your DLL to `PATH` variable and then the system will be able to find it. But that is only one of the places system looks for the DLL in. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx) is a full description. In short the most important places in order of search are:

- The directory from which the application loaded.
- The system directory.
- The Windows directory.
- The current directory.
- The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

So this explains why adding to `PATH` works and is also considered a normal approach, since tweaking with the current directory (which you can do) can do bad stuff.

2) In this scenario you are on your own. [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx) gives the ability to alter your search path, by using [SetDefaultDllDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310515(v=vs.85).aspx) or `LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH` to load the DLL and any dependencies.

Comment: Is it possible to use the dll via its lib file and do a  Run-Time Dynamic Linking?

Comment: @GernotLepej - you don't event need the `lib` file. What you do is use `LoadLibraryEx` with the dll file name and then call `GetProcAddress` to get pointer/pointers to the needed functions and just call these pointers the same way you would call the functions if you were using a `lib` file`. MSDN has a good example here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64tkc9y5.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Add the folder containing the DLL to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: During run-time? How?

Comment: why would you do that during run-time? just do it before you start the program

Comment: Because this runs not only on my machine, it runs on customers machine. So I could do this during the installation process?

Comment: @GernotLepej yes, you should do this during your installation process. the details depend on which installing mechanism you use.